# Understanding a str.replace() behavior in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a series which contains amounts as strings some of which are malformed and I want to clean it to convert it to floats.

In particular there is an entry `($25.0)`.  I want to remove the `($` first and then `)`.

I start with the following code:

```
s = s.str.replace('($', '', regex = False)
```

The string `'($'` is removed but then some rows turn to NaNs:

Before:

```
442452        992
442453       2415
442454      177.5
442455      32457
442456    4714.07
Name: Amount, dtype: object
```

After:

```
442452    NaN
442453    NaN
442454    NaN
442455    NaN
442456    NaN
Name: Amount, dtype: object
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Wouldn't `s.str.strip('$()')` be simpler? Also - are you sure they're malformed and that the (...) notion isn't indicating they should actually be considered as negative amounts for instance?

Comment: @JonClements makes a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely that `NaN` rows are not strings, they may be numeric type or something else. Try to check `type` of rows returning `NaN` as follows

```
s[s.str.replace('($', '', regex=False).isna()].map(type)
```

If your issue is exactly as I guess, the solution is converting whole `s` to string before `replace`

```
s.astype(str).str.replace('($', '', regex=False)
```

Or chaining addition `fillna` after replace to put back those numeric values

```
s.str.replace('($', '', regex=False).fillna(s)
```

---

For example below sample creates a series of dtype object where 1st row is integer and the rest are strings.

```
s = pd.Series([123, '($2.0)', 'B03', 'D04'])

Out[416]:
0       123
1    ($2.0)
2       B03
3       D04
dtype: object
```

`str.replace` turns 1st row to `NaN`

```
s.str.replace('($', '', regex=False)

Out[417]:
0     NaN
1    2.0)
2     B03
3     D04
dtype: object
```

Use `map(type)` to check `NaN` row datatype showing it is integer

```
s[s.str.replace('($', '', regex=False).isna()].map(type)

Out[418]:
0    <class 'int'>
dtype: object
```